# How to change file size unit in media library in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I am currently using Sitecore 6.6. I wonder how to override the display unit from byte to megabyte?

Does it need to change the xml here sitecore\shell\Applications\Files and what class should be overwrote?

[image]

Comment: it's bad practice to do it. The size in bytes is added automatically when you upload a media file.   why do you want to change it?

Comment: Because the users want to have a easier way to understand the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to make any change in this as it is out of the box from Sitecore.

If you still want it for a very specific purpose like your Site Manager (Person who add/edit the content of the Site) to see the size in MB or KB then you may add some custom code.

- Add a field in the Template
- Write a Pipeline and add it in uiUpload in Sitecore.config. This Pipeline should count the size of the uploaded file and then convert it in KBs or MBs as you desired.